# System becomes unresponsive on lock screen - how to debug?

Tags: fedora, freeze

I'm running a system (Fedora 27) which often freezes completely when I've been away from the computer for a while. 
As I am running computation in the background, I can tell that the freeze happens anywhere from minutes to hours after I've locked the computer.
The computer is running, but is otherwise completely unresponsive (screen doesn't turn on, num lock on keyboard does nothing, etc).

Where would I start to debug this? What log files might help me figure out what the problem is? The computer never freezes while I'm working at it, which obviously makes me suspect that it's related to GDM turning the screen off,but I'm unable to find other people with similar problems.

Comment: Try this when it gets unresponsive:- Close the lid wait for 5 seconds and then open the lid. It will bring the `gdm` login screen.

Comment: Tricky, as it's a desktop ;) That being said, after turning it off, it does usually need somehting like 20s before I can turn it on again.

Comment: Can you access the TTY screens (Alt-Ctrl-F1 ... Alft-Ctrl-F6) and login there?

Comment: No, completely unresponsive.  Screens are turned off, none of the standard keyboard shortcuts work (Alt-Ctrl-F1 , Alt-Ctrl-Backspace,  shortpressing the power button).

Comment: Does it respond to a `ssh` from another machine?

Answer (score 1):

Both software and hardware failure may be a reason behind the system freezing issue. I'll suggest to diagnose step-wise.

To, check any software issue in this situation easiest way to boot the system using a live disk like Ubntu etc and check whether the issue is still exists. If, the issue is persistent with live disk also it's mostly a hardware issue.

If your system is working fine with live disk, login back to your installed system and check `xorg` log file usually in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` [Replace `0` with other numbers for older logs]. Probably you'll find some insight there. Also check the system's power environment i.e. sleep time, hibernation time etc in current installation.

Press `alt+f2` to login into `tty` instead `GUI` and check whether the issue is still exists or not. If the issue doesn't appear in `tty` it may be a display driver issue.

Also ensure any random key from keyboard is pressing due to hardware fault. Open a terminal and type `xev` while logged into `GUI`. This will show all input key stock and mouse movement.

Also ensure any cable loose connection in case your mentioned system is a desktop.